# How to validate number of radio box and highlight it if radio box are not checked?

Tags: jquery, css

```js
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $('#showme').click(function() {
        validateNresult() ;
    })
   
});

function validateNresult() 
{
        var names = []
        $('.allrb').each(function () {
            var rname = $(this).attr('name');
            if ($.inArray(rname, names) == -1) names.push(rname);
        });

        $.each(names, function (i, name) {
            if ($('input[name="' + name + '"]:checked').length == 0) 
            {
                $(this).addClass("invalid");
            }

            else
            {
                $(this).removeClass("invalid");
            }

        });
}
```

```css
input[type=radio] {
      position: absolute;
      visibility: hidden;
      display: inline-block;
    }

    label {
      color: #9a929e;
      display: inline-block;
      cursor: pointer;
      font-weight: bold;
      padding: 5px 20px;
      margin: auto;
    }

    input[type=radio]:checked + label {
      color: #ccc8ce;
      background: #675f6b;
      margin: auto;
    }

    label + input[type=radio] + label {
      border-left: solid 3px #675f6b;
    }

    .radio-group {
      border: solid 3px #675f6b;
      display: inline-block;
      margin: 10px;
      border-radius: 10px;
      overflow: hidden;
    font-family: roboto;
    }

    table
    {
        margin-top: 20px;
    }

    #tab td
    {
        vertical-align:middle;
    }
 
 ul li
 {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
 }
 
 ul li input
 {
  text-align: center;
 }

    .invalid 
    {
      outline: 1px solid red;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-responsive table-striped table-hover " id="tab">
  <tbody>
    <tr id="alertr1" name="v">
      <td width="30px">1</td>
      <td width="200px">Content</td>
      <td width="75px;">
        <div class="radio-group">
          <input type="radio" id="option-one" name="r1" class="allrb thinker" value="5"><label for="option-one">A</label><input type="radio" id="option-two" name="r1" class="allrb thinker" value="4"><label for="option-two">B</label><input type="radio"
            id="option-three" name="r1" class="allrb thinker" value="3"><label for="option-three">C</label><input type="radio" id="option-four" name="r1" class="allrb thinker" value="2"><label for="option-four">D</label><input type="radio" id="option-five"
            name="r1" class="allrb thinker" value="1"><label for="option-five">E</label>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="alertr2" name="v">
      <td width="30px">2</td>
      <td width="200px">Content</td>
      <td width="75px;">
        <div class="radio-group">
          <input type="radio" id="option-one2" name="r2" class="allrb expresser" value="5"><label for="option-one2">A</label><input type="radio" id="option-two2" name="r2" class="allrb expresser" value="4"><label for="option-two2">B</label><input type="radio"
            id="option-three2" name="r2" class="allrb expresser" value="3"><label for="option-three2">C</label><input type="radio" id="option-four2" name="r2" class="allrb expresser" value="2"><label for="option-four2">D</label><input type="radio" id="option-five2"
            name="r2" class="allrb expresser" value="1"><label for="option-five2">E</label>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="alertr3" name="v">
      <td width="30px">3</td>
      <td width="200px">Content</td>
      <td width="75px;">
        <div class="radio-group">
          <input type="radio" id="option-one3" name="r3" class="allrb director" value="1"><label for="option-one3">A</label><input type="radio" id="option-two3" name="r3" class="allrb director" value="2"><label for="option-two3">B</label><input type="radio"
            id="option-three3" name="r3" class="allrb director" value="3"><label for="option-three3">C</label><input type="radio" id="option-four3" name="r3" class="allrb director" value="4"><label for="option-four3">D</label><input type="radio" id="option-five3"
            name="r3" class="allrb director" value="5"><label for="option-five3">E</label>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="alertr4" name="v">
      <td width="30px">4</td>
      <td width="200px">Content</td>
      <td width="75px;">
        <div class="radio-group">
          <input type="radio" id="option-one4" name="r4" class="allrb harmonizer" value="5"><label for="option-one4">A</label><input type="radio" id="option-two4" name="r4" class="allrb harmonizer" value="4"><label for="option-two4">B</label><input type="radio"
            id="option-three4" name="r4" class="allrb harmonizer" value="3"><label for="option-three4">C</label><input type="radio" id="option-four4" name="r4" class="allrb harmonizer" value="2"><label for="option-four4">D</label><input type="radio" id="option-five4"
            name="r4" class="allrb harmonizer" value="1"><label for="option-five4">E</label>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="alertr5" name="v">
      <td width="30px">5</td>
      <td width="200px">Content</td>
      <td width="75px;">
        <div class="radio-group">
          <input type="radio" id="option-one5" name="r5" class="allrb thinker" value="5"><label for="option-one5">A</label><input type="radio" id="option-two5" name="r5" class="allrb thinker" value="4"><label for="option-two5">B</label><input type="radio"
            id="option-three5" name="r5" class="allrb thinker" value="3"><label for="option-three5">C</label><input type="radio" id="option-four5" name="r5" class="allrb thinker" value="2"><label for="option-four5">D</label><input type="radio" id="option-five5"
            name="r5" class="allrb thinker" value="1"><label for="option-five5">E</label>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="alertr6" name="v">
      <td width="30px">6</td>
      <td width="200px">Content</td>
      <td width="75px;">
        <div class="radio-group">
          <input type="radio" id="option-one6" name="r6" class="allrb director" value="1"><label for="option-one6">A</label><input type="radio" id="option-two6" name="r6" class="allrb director" value="2"><label for="option-two6">B</label><input type="radio"
            id="option-three6" name="r6" class="allrb director" value="3"><label for="option-three6">C</label><input type="radio" id="option-four6" name="r6" class="allrb director" value="4"><label for="option-four6">D</label><input type="radio" id="option-five6"
            name="r6" class="allrb director" value="5"><label for="option-five6">E</label>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="alertr7" name="v">
      <td width="30px">7</td>
      <td width="200px">Content</td>
      <td width="75px;">
        <div class="radio-group">
          <input type="radio" id="option-one7" name="r7" class="allrb thinker" value="5"><label for="option-one7">A</label><input type="radio" id="option-two7" name="r7" class="allrb thinker" value="4"><label for="option-two7">B</label><input type="radio"
            id="option-three7" name="r7" class="allrb thinker" value="3"><label for="option-three7">C</label><input type="radio" id="option-four7" name="r7" class="allrb thinker" value="2"><label for="option-four7">D</label><input type="radio" id="option-five7"
            name="r7" class="allrb thinker" value="1"><label for="option-five7">E</label>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="alertr8" name="v">
      <td width="30px">8</td>
      <td width="200px">Content</td>
      <td width="75px;">
        <div class="radio-group">
          <input type="radio" id="option-one8" name="r8" class="allrb expresser" value="1"><label for="option-one8">A</label><input type="radio" id="option-two8" name="r8" class="allrb expresser" value="2"><label for="option-two8">B</label><input type="radio"
            id="option-three8" name="r8" class="allrb expresser" value="3"><label for="option-three8">C</label><input type="radio" id="option-four8" name="r8" class="allrb expresser" value="4"><label for="option-four8">D</label><input type="radio" id="option-five8"
            name="r8" class="allrb expresser" value="5"><label for="option-five8">E</label>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="alertr9" name="v">
      <td width="30px">9</td>
      <td width="200px">Content</td>
      <td width="75px;">
        <div class="radio-group">
          <input type="radio" id="option-one9" name="r9" class="allrb harmonizer" value="1"><label for="option-one9">A</label><input type="radio" id="option-two9" name="r9" class="allrb harmonizer" value="2"><label for="option-two9">B</label><input type="radio"
            id="option-three9" name="r9" class="allrb harmonizer" value="3"><label for="option-three9">C</label><input type="radio" id="option-four9" name="r9" class="allrb harmonizer" value="4"><label for="option-four9">D</label><input type="radio" id="option-five9"
            name="r9" class="allrb harmonizer" value="5"><label for="option-five9">E</label>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>

<button class="btn btn-primary" id="showme" type="button">View Result</button>
```

I had 32 radio button with different name had to be validate. I had do some research and change around my code, but it is not working for me. I want to highlight the entire table row to be red if user didn't select the radio box, all radio box should be selected before getting their result. Can someone show me the correct way? Thanks.

I had also try to use `document.getElementsByName(name).style.outline = "thin solid red";` but it show me the error which is

> Cannot set property 'outline' of undefined

Comment: `document.getElementsByName(name)` returns array, so array do not have `.style.outline`. Use `document.getElementsByName(name)[0].style.outline`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if below code helps! it will highlight whole div if no any checkbox is checked in that.

If you want to highlight around checkbox then consider uncomment/comment the lines in code of adding/removing class.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#showme').click(function() {
    validateNresult();
  })

});

function validateNresult() {
 
  $('.allrb').each(function() {
    var rname = $(this).attr('name');
    var parentDiv = $(this).parents("div");
    if (parentDiv.find("[name='" + rname + "']:checked").length > 0) {
      parentDiv.removeClass("invalid");//to highlight div
      //$(this).next("label").removeClass("invalid");//to highlight around checkbox
    } else {
      parentDiv.addClass("invalid");
      //$(this).next("label").addClass("invalid");
      
    }

  });

}
```

```css
input[type=radio] {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}

label {
  color: #9a929e;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  margin: auto;
}

input[type=radio]:checked+label {
  color: #ccc8ce;
  background: #675f6b;
  margin: auto;
}

label+input[type=radio]+label {
  border-left: solid 3px #675f6b;
}

.radio-group {
  border: solid 3px #675f6b;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: roboto;
}

table {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#tab td {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

ul li input {
  text-align: center;
}

.invalid {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-responsive table-striped table-hover " id="tab">
  <tbody>
    <tr id="alertr1" name="v">
      <td width="30px">1</td>
      <td width="200px">Content</td>
      <td width="75px;">
        <div class="radio-group">
          <input type="radio" id="option-one" name="r1" class="allrb thinker" value="5"><label for="option-one">A</label><input type="radio" id="option-two" name="r1" class="allrb thinker" value="4"><label for="option-two">B</label><input type="radio"
            id="option-three" name="r1" class="allrb thinker" value="3"><label for="option-three">C</label><input type="radio" id="option-four" name="r1" class="allrb thinker" value="2"><label for="option-four">D</label><input type="radio" id="option-five"
            name="r1" class="allrb thinker" value="1"><label for="option-five">E</label>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="alertr2" name="v">
      <td width="30px">2</td>
      <td width="200px">Content</td>
      <td width="75px;">
        <div class="radio-group">
          <input type="radio" id="option-one2" name="r2" class="allrb expresser" value="5"><label for="option-one2">A</label><input type="radio" id="option-two2" name="r2" class="allrb expresser" value="4"><label for="option-two2">B</label><input type="radio"
            id="option-three2" name="r2" class="allrb expresser" value="3"><label for="option-three2">C</label><input type="radio" id="option-four2" name="r2" class="allrb expresser" value="2"><label for="option-four2">D</label><input type="radio" id="option-five2"
            name="r2" class="allrb expresser" value="1"><label for="option-five2">E</label>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="alertr3" name="v">
      <td width="30px">3</td>
      <td width="200px">Content</td>
      <td width="75px;">
        <div class="radio-group">
          <input type="radio" id="option-one3" name="r3" class="allrb director" value="1"><label for="option-one3">A</label><input type="radio" id="option-two3" name="r3" class="allrb director" value="2"><label for="option-two3">B</label><input type="radio"
            id="option-three3" name="r3" class="allrb director" value="3"><label for="option-three3">C</label><input type="radio" id="option-four3" name="r3" class="allrb director" value="4"><label for="option-four3">D</label><input type="radio" id="option-five3"
            name="r3" class="allrb director" value="5"><label for="option-five3">E</label>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="alertr4" name="v">
      <td width="30px">4</td>
      <td width="200px">Content</td>
      <td width="75px;">
        <div class="radio-group">
          <input type="radio" id="option-one4" name="r4" class="allrb harmonizer" value="5"><label for="option-one4">A</label><input type="radio" id="option-two4" name="r4" class="allrb harmonizer" value="4"><label for="option-two4">B</label><input type="radio"
            id="option-three4" name="r4" class="allrb harmonizer" value="3"><label for="option-three4">C</label><input type="radio" id="option-four4" name="r4" class="allrb harmonizer" value="2"><label for="option-four4">D</label><input type="radio" id="option-five4"
            name="r4" class="allrb harmonizer" value="1"><label for="option-five4">E</label>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="alertr5" name="v">
      <td width="30px">5</td>
      <td width="200px">Content</td>
      <td width="75px;">
        <div class="radio-group">
          <input type="radio" id="option-one5" name="r5" class="allrb thinker" value="5"><label for="option-one5">A</label><input type="radio" id="option-two5" name="r5" class="allrb thinker" value="4"><label for="option-two5">B</label><input type="radio"
            id="option-three5" name="r5" class="allrb thinker" value="3"><label for="option-three5">C</label><input type="radio" id="option-four5" name="r5" class="allrb thinker" value="2"><label for="option-four5">D</label><input type="radio" id="option-five5"
            name="r5" class="allrb thinker" value="1"><label for="option-five5">E</label>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="alertr6" name="v">
      <td width="30px">6</td>
      <td width="200px">Content</td>
      <td width="75px;">
        <div class="radio-group">
          <input type="radio" id="option-one6" name="r6" class="allrb director" value="1"><label for="option-one6">A</label><input type="radio" id="option-two6" name="r6" class="allrb director" value="2"><label for="option-two6">B</label><input type="radio"
            id="option-three6" name="r6" class="allrb director" value="3"><label for="option-three6">C</label><input type="radio" id="option-four6" name="r6" class="allrb director" value="4"><label for="option-four6">D</label><input type="radio" id="option-five6"
            name="r6" class="allrb director" value="5"><label for="option-five6">E</label>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="alertr7" name="v">
      <td width="30px">7</td>
      <td width="200px">Content</td>
      <td width="75px;">
        <div class="radio-group">
          <input type="radio" id="option-one7" name="r7" class="allrb thinker" value="5"><label for="option-one7">A</label><input type="radio" id="option-two7" name="r7" class="allrb thinker" value="4"><label for="option-two7">B</label><input type="radio"
            id="option-three7" name="r7" class="allrb thinker" value="3"><label for="option-three7">C</label><input type="radio" id="option-four7" name="r7" class="allrb thinker" value="2"><label for="option-four7">D</label><input type="radio" id="option-five7"
            name="r7" class="allrb thinker" value="1"><label for="option-five7">E</label>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="alertr8" name="v">
      <td width="30px">8</td>
      <td width="200px">Content</td>
      <td width="75px;">
        <div class="radio-group">
          <input type="radio" id="option-one8" name="r8" class="allrb expresser" value="1"><label for="option-one8">A</label><input type="radio" id="option-two8" name="r8" class="allrb expresser" value="2"><label for="option-two8">B</label><input type="radio"
            id="option-three8" name="r8" class="allrb expresser" value="3"><label for="option-three8">C</label><input type="radio" id="option-four8" name="r8" class="allrb expresser" value="4"><label for="option-four8">D</label><input type="radio" id="option-five8"
            name="r8" class="allrb expresser" value="5"><label for="option-five8">E</label>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="alertr9" name="v">
      <td width="30px">9</td>
      <td width="200px">Content</td>
      <td width="75px;">
        <div class="radio-group">
          <input type="radio" id="option-one9" name="r9" class="allrb harmonizer" value="1"><label for="option-one9">A</label><input type="radio" id="option-two9" name="r9" class="allrb harmonizer" value="2"><label for="option-two9">B</label><input type="radio"
            id="option-three9" name="r9" class="allrb harmonizer" value="3"><label for="option-three9">C</label><input type="radio" id="option-four9" name="r9" class="allrb harmonizer" value="4"><label for="option-four9">D</label><input type="radio" id="option-five9"
            name="r9" class="allrb harmonizer" value="5"><label for="option-five9">E</label>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>

<button class="btn btn-primary" id="showme" type="button">View Result</button>
```

Comment: Hi, this is good, but do you know how to highlight entire row instead of its radio box div? =) Just change the border to outline is it?

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $('#showme').click(function() {
        validateNresult() ;
    })
   
});

function validateNresult() 
{
        var names = []
        $('.allrb').each(function () {
            var rname = $(this).attr('name');
            if ($.inArray(rname, names) == -1) names.push(rname);
        });

        $.each(names, function (i, name) {
            if ($('input[name="' + name + '"]:checked').length == 0) 
            {
                //$(this).addClass("invalid");
                $('input[name="' + name + '"]').eq(0).closest('.radio-group').addClass("invalid");
            }

            else
            {
                //$(this).removeClass("invalid");
                $('input[name="' + name + '"]').eq(0).closest('.radio-group').removeClass("invalid");
            }

        });
}
```

```css
input[type=radio] {
      position: absolute;
      visibility: hidden;
      display: inline-block;
    }

    label {
      color: #9a929e;
      display: inline-block;
      cursor: pointer;
      font-weight: bold;
      padding: 5px 20px;
      margin: auto;
    }

    input[type=radio]:checked + label {
      color: #ccc8ce;
      background: #675f6b;
      margin: auto;
    }

    label + input[type=radio] + label {
      border-left: solid 3px #675f6b;
    }

    .radio-group {
      border: solid 3px #675f6b;
      display: inline-block;
      margin: 10px;
      border-radius: 10px;
      overflow: hidden;
    font-family: roboto;
    }

    table
    {
        margin-top: 20px;
    }

    #tab td
    {
        vertical-align:middle;
    }
 
 ul li
 {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
 }
 
 ul li input
 {
  text-align: center;
 }

    .invalid 
    {
      /*outline: 1px solid red;*/
      border-color: red
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-responsive table-striped table-hover " id="tab">
  <tbody>
    <tr id="alertr1" name="v">
      <td width="30px">1</td>
      <td width="200px">Content</td>
      <td width="75px;">
        <div class="radio-group">
          <input type="radio" id="option-one" name="r1" class="allrb thinker" value="5"><label for="option-one">A</label><input type="radio" id="option-two" name="r1" class="allrb thinker" value="4"><label for="option-two">B</label><input type="radio"
            id="option-three" name="r1" class="allrb thinker" value="3"><label for="option-three">C</label><input type="radio" id="option-four" name="r1" class="allrb thinker" value="2"><label for="option-four">D</label><input type="radio" id="option-five"
            name="r1" class="allrb thinker" value="1"><label for="option-five">E</label>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="alertr2" name="v">
      <td width="30px">2</td>
      <td width="200px">Content</td>
      <td width="75px;">
        <div class="radio-group">
          <input type="radio" id="option-one2" name="r2" class="allrb expresser" value="5"><label for="option-one2">A</label><input type="radio" id="option-two2" name="r2" class="allrb expresser" value="4"><label for="option-two2">B</label><input type="radio"
            id="option-three2" name="r2" class="allrb expresser" value="3"><label for="option-three2">C</label><input type="radio" id="option-four2" name="r2" class="allrb expresser" value="2"><label for="option-four2">D</label><input type="radio" id="option-five2"
            name="r2" class="allrb expresser" value="1"><label for="option-five2">E</label>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="alertr3" name="v">
      <td width="30px">3</td>
      <td width="200px">Content</td>
      <td width="75px;">
        <div class="radio-group">
          <input type="radio" id="option-one3" name="r3" class="allrb director" value="1"><label for="option-one3">A</label><input type="radio" id="option-two3" name="r3" class="allrb director" value="2"><label for="option-two3">B</label><input type="radio"
            id="option-three3" name="r3" class="allrb director" value="3"><label for="option-three3">C</label><input type="radio" id="option-four3" name="r3" class="allrb director" value="4"><label for="option-four3">D</label><input type="radio" id="option-five3"
            name="r3" class="allrb director" value="5"><label for="option-five3">E</label>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="alertr4" name="v">
      <td width="30px">4</td>
      <td width="200px">Content</td>
      <td width="75px;">
        <div class="radio-group">
          <input type="radio" id="option-one4" name="r4" class="allrb harmonizer" value="5"><label for="option-one4">A</label><input type="radio" id="option-two4" name="r4" class="allrb harmonizer" value="4"><label for="option-two4">B</label><input type="radio"
            id="option-three4" name="r4" class="allrb harmonizer" value="3"><label for="option-three4">C</label><input type="radio" id="option-four4" name="r4" class="allrb harmonizer" value="2"><label for="option-four4">D</label><input type="radio" id="option-five4"
            name="r4" class="allrb harmonizer" value="1"><label for="option-five4">E</label>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="alertr5" name="v">
      <td width="30px">5</td>
      <td width="200px">Content</td>
      <td width="75px;">
        <div class="radio-group">
          <input type="radio" id="option-one5" name="r5" class="allrb thinker" value="5"><label for="option-one5">A</label><input type="radio" id="option-two5" name="r5" class="allrb thinker" value="4"><label for="option-two5">B</label><input type="radio"
            id="option-three5" name="r5" class="allrb thinker" value="3"><label for="option-three5">C</label><input type="radio" id="option-four5" name="r5" class="allrb thinker" value="2"><label for="option-four5">D</label><input type="radio" id="option-five5"
            name="r5" class="allrb thinker" value="1"><label for="option-five5">E</label>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="alertr6" name="v">
      <td width="30px">6</td>
      <td width="200px">Content</td>
      <td width="75px;">
        <div class="radio-group">
          <input type="radio" id="option-one6" name="r6" class="allrb director" value="1"><label for="option-one6">A</label><input type="radio" id="option-two6" name="r6" class="allrb director" value="2"><label for="option-two6">B</label><input type="radio"
            id="option-three6" name="r6" class="allrb director" value="3"><label for="option-three6">C</label><input type="radio" id="option-four6" name="r6" class="allrb director" value="4"><label for="option-four6">D</label><input type="radio" id="option-five6"
            name="r6" class="allrb director" value="5"><label for="option-five6">E</label>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="alertr7" name="v">
      <td width="30px">7</td>
      <td width="200px">Content</td>
      <td width="75px;">
        <div class="radio-group">
          <input type="radio" id="option-one7" name="r7" class="allrb thinker" value="5"><label for="option-one7">A</label><input type="radio" id="option-two7" name="r7" class="allrb thinker" value="4"><label for="option-two7">B</label><input type="radio"
            id="option-three7" name="r7" class="allrb thinker" value="3"><label for="option-three7">C</label><input type="radio" id="option-four7" name="r7" class="allrb thinker" value="2"><label for="option-four7">D</label><input type="radio" id="option-five7"
            name="r7" class="allrb thinker" value="1"><label for="option-five7">E</label>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="alertr8" name="v">
      <td width="30px">8</td>
      <td width="200px">Content</td>
      <td width="75px;">
        <div class="radio-group">
          <input type="radio" id="option-one8" name="r8" class="allrb expresser" value="1"><label for="option-one8">A</label><input type="radio" id="option-two8" name="r8" class="allrb expresser" value="2"><label for="option-two8">B</label><input type="radio"
            id="option-three8" name="r8" class="allrb expresser" value="3"><label for="option-three8">C</label><input type="radio" id="option-four8" name="r8" class="allrb expresser" value="4"><label for="option-four8">D</label><input type="radio" id="option-five8"
            name="r8" class="allrb expresser" value="5"><label for="option-five8">E</label>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="alertr9" name="v">
      <td width="30px">9</td>
      <td width="200px">Content</td>
      <td width="75px;">
        <div class="radio-group">
          <input type="radio" id="option-one9" name="r9" class="allrb harmonizer" value="1"><label for="option-one9">A</label><input type="radio" id="option-two9" name="r9" class="allrb harmonizer" value="2"><label for="option-two9">B</label><input type="radio"
            id="option-three9" name="r9" class="allrb harmonizer" value="3"><label for="option-three9">C</label><input type="radio" id="option-four9" name="r9" class="allrb harmonizer" value="4"><label for="option-four9">D</label><input type="radio" id="option-five9"
            name="r9" class="allrb harmonizer" value="5"><label for="option-five9">E</label>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>

<button class="btn btn-primary" id="showme" type="button">View Result</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me know if this works for you.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#showme').click(function() {
    validateNresult();
  });
});

function validateNresult() {
  $("tr[name='v']").each(function() {
    if ($(this).find("input:checked").length == 0) {
      $(this).css("background-color", "red");
    }
  });
};
```

```css
input[type=radio] {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}

label {
  color: #9a929e;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  margin: auto;
}

input[type=radio]:checked+label {
  color: #ccc8ce;
  background: #675f6b;
  margin: auto;
}

label+input[type=radio]+label {
  border-left: solid 3px #675f6b;
}

.radio-group {
  border: solid 3px #675f6b;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: roboto;
}

table {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#tab td {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

ul li input {
  text-align: center;
}

.invalid {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-responsive table-striped table-hover " id="tab">
  <tbody>
    <tr id="alertr1" name="v">
      <td width="30px">1</td>
      <td width="200px">Content</td>
      <td width="75px;">
        <div class="radio-group">
          <input type="radio" id="option-one" name="r1" class="allrb thinker" value="5"><label for="option-one">A</label><input type="radio" id="option-two" name="r1" class="allrb thinker" value="4"><label for="option-two">B</label><input type="radio"
            id="option-three" name="r1" class="allrb thinker" value="3"><label for="option-three">C</label><input type="radio" id="option-four" name="r1" class="allrb thinker" value="2"><label for="option-four">D</label><input type="radio" id="option-five"
            name="r1" class="allrb thinker" value="1"><label for="option-five">E</label>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="alertr2" name="v">
      <td width="30px">2</td>
      <td width="200px">Content</td>
      <td width="75px;">
        <div class="radio-group">
          <input type="radio" id="option-one2" name="r2" class="allrb expresser" value="5"><label for="option-one2">A</label><input type="radio" id="option-two2" name="r2" class="allrb expresser" value="4"><label for="option-two2">B</label><input type="radio"
            id="option-three2" name="r2" class="allrb expresser" value="3"><label for="option-three2">C</label><input type="radio" id="option-four2" name="r2" class="allrb expresser" value="2"><label for="option-four2">D</label><input type="radio" id="option-five2"
            name="r2" class="allrb expresser" value="1"><label for="option-five2">E</label>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="alertr3" name="v">
      <td width="30px">3</td>
      <td width="200px">Content</td>
      <td width="75px;">
        <div class="radio-group">
          <input type="radio" id="option-one3" name="r3" class="allrb director" value="1"><label for="option-one3">A</label><input type="radio" id="option-two3" name="r3" class="allrb director" value="2"><label for="option-two3">B</label><input type="radio"
            id="option-three3" name="r3" class="allrb director" value="3"><label for="option-three3">C</label><input type="radio" id="option-four3" name="r3" class="allrb director" value="4"><label for="option-four3">D</label><input type="radio" id="option-five3"
            name="r3" class="allrb director" value="5"><label for="option-five3">E</label>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="alertr4" name="v">
      <td width="30px">4</td>
      <td width="200px">Content</td>
      <td width="75px;">
        <div class="radio-group">
          <input type="radio" id="option-one4" name="r4" class="allrb harmonizer" value="5"><label for="option-one4">A</label><input type="radio" id="option-two4" name="r4" class="allrb harmonizer" value="4"><label for="option-two4">B</label><input type="radio"
            id="option-three4" name="r4" class="allrb harmonizer" value="3"><label for="option-three4">C</label><input type="radio" id="option-four4" name="r4" class="allrb harmonizer" value="2"><label for="option-four4">D</label><input type="radio" id="option-five4"
            name="r4" class="allrb harmonizer" value="1"><label for="option-five4">E</label>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="alertr5" name="v">
      <td width="30px">5</td>
      <td width="200px">Content</td>
      <td width="75px;">
        <div class="radio-group">
          <input type="radio" id="option-one5" name="r5" class="allrb thinker" value="5"><label for="option-one5">A</label><input type="radio" id="option-two5" name="r5" class="allrb thinker" value="4"><label for="option-two5">B</label><input type="radio"
            id="option-three5" name="r5" class="allrb thinker" value="3"><label for="option-three5">C</label><input type="radio" id="option-four5" name="r5" class="allrb thinker" value="2"><label for="option-four5">D</label><input type="radio" id="option-five5"
            name="r5" class="allrb thinker" value="1"><label for="option-five5">E</label>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="alertr6" name="v">
      <td width="30px">6</td>
      <td width="200px">Content</td>
      <td width="75px;">
        <div class="radio-group">
          <input type="radio" id="option-one6" name="r6" class="allrb director" value="1"><label for="option-one6">A</label><input type="radio" id="option-two6" name="r6" class="allrb director" value="2"><label for="option-two6">B</label><input type="radio"
            id="option-three6" name="r6" class="allrb director" value="3"><label for="option-three6">C</label><input type="radio" id="option-four6" name="r6" class="allrb director" value="4"><label for="option-four6">D</label><input type="radio" id="option-five6"
            name="r6" class="allrb director" value="5"><label for="option-five6">E</label>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="alertr7" name="v">
      <td width="30px">7</td>
      <td width="200px">Content</td>
      <td width="75px;">
        <div class="radio-group">
          <input type="radio" id="option-one7" name="r7" class="allrb thinker" value="5"><label for="option-one7">A</label><input type="radio" id="option-two7" name="r7" class="allrb thinker" value="4"><label for="option-two7">B</label><input type="radio"
            id="option-three7" name="r7" class="allrb thinker" value="3"><label for="option-three7">C</label><input type="radio" id="option-four7" name="r7" class="allrb thinker" value="2"><label for="option-four7">D</label><input type="radio" id="option-five7"
            name="r7" class="allrb thinker" value="1"><label for="option-five7">E</label>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="alertr8" name="v">
      <td width="30px">8</td>
      <td width="200px">Content</td>
      <td width="75px;">
        <div class="radio-group">
          <input type="radio" id="option-one8" name="r8" class="allrb expresser" value="1"><label for="option-one8">A</label><input type="radio" id="option-two8" name="r8" class="allrb expresser" value="2"><label for="option-two8">B</label><input type="radio"
            id="option-three8" name="r8" class="allrb expresser" value="3"><label for="option-three8">C</label><input type="radio" id="option-four8" name="r8" class="allrb expresser" value="4"><label for="option-four8">D</label><input type="radio" id="option-five8"
            name="r8" class="allrb expresser" value="5"><label for="option-five8">E</label>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="alertr9" name="v">
      <td width="30px">9</td>
      <td width="200px">Content</td>
      <td width="75px;">
        <div class="radio-group">
          <input type="radio" id="option-one9" name="r9" class="allrb harmonizer" value="1"><label for="option-one9">A</label><input type="radio" id="option-two9" name="r9" class="allrb harmonizer" value="2"><label for="option-two9">B</label><input type="radio"
            id="option-three9" name="r9" class="allrb harmonizer" value="3"><label for="option-three9">C</label><input type="radio" id="option-four9" name="r9" class="allrb harmonizer" value="4"><label for="option-four9">D</label><input type="radio" id="option-five9"
            name="r9" class="allrb harmonizer" value="5"><label for="option-five9">E</label>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>

<button class="btn btn-primary" id="showme" type="button">View Result</button>
```

Comment: Yes, it is working fine and is more simple and short code! Cheers =D